# How to initialize javascript var with a bool value in razor

Tags: javascript, razorengine

```
<script>
  var showLowPrice = @Model.ShowLowPrice;
  if(showLowPrice){
    window.alert("LowPrice");
  }
</script>
```

But when this gets rendered it looks like this

```
<script>
  var showLowPrice = True;
  if(showLowPrice){
    window.alert("LowPrice");
  }
</script>
```

and the alert does not show up

Here is the model

```
public class Store
    {
        public Store() {
          Suggestions = "[]";
          SearchTerm = "";
          ShowLowPrice = true;
        }      
        public string Suggestions { get; set; }
        public string SearchTerm { get; set; }
        public bool ShowLowPrice { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Try `var showLowPrice = @Model.ShowLowPrice.ToString().ToLower();`

Comment: Show us the c# model